# How to fix newline character in csv exported in shell script?

Tags: shell, csv, unix

I want to fix this below issue in csv file using unix. I don't have access to source so i have to fix with this csv file alone. I need to desired output. is it achievable. Please help.

I have tried this below code but it doesn't work.

```
perl -p00e 's/\n|/|/g' test.csv
```

Issue:

```
DATECODE|SUBCLASSCODE|SUBCLASS_NAME|CLASS
2021-05-25|2202|Bras|1310
2021-05-25|1119|No Longer in Use - Depleted by 2019 Reclass|0805
2021-05-25|0949|No Longer in Use - Depleted by 2021 Reclass|0231
2021-05-25|1928|Fishing Gloves|1155
2021-05-25|1604|Training FW|1080
2021-05-25|0894|Hunting Waders|0894
2021-05-25|1873|Small Game|0326
2021-05-25|9950|EVENT
REGISTRATION FEE|9950
2021-05-25|0476|Regular Golf Gloves|0476
2021-05-25|1366|
Shorts|0988
2021-05-25|1914|Wade Shoes|0894
2021-05-25|0537|No Longer in Use - Depleted by 2019 Reclass|0537
2021-05-25|1635|Pickleball FW|
0021
2021-05-25|0679|Case Sunglasses|0679
2021-05-25|1544|Sandals|0001
2021-05-25|
1527|Golf/Tennis Accessories|1059
2021-05-25|1582|Lifestyle FW|0502
```

Desired Result:

```
DATECODE|SUBCLASSCODE|SUBCLASS_NAME|CLASS
2021-05-25|2202|Bras|1310
2021-05-25|1119|No Longer in Use - Depleted by 2019 Reclass|0805
2021-05-25|0949|No Longer in Use - Depleted by 2021 Reclass|0231
2021-05-25|1928|Fishing Gloves|1155
2021-05-25|1604|Training FW|1080
2021-05-25|0894|Hunting Waders|0894
2021-05-25|1873|Small Game|0326
2021-05-25|9950|EVENT REGISTRATION FEE|9950
2021-05-25|0476|Regular Golf Gloves|0476
2021-05-25|1366|Shorts|0988
2021-05-25|1914|Wade Shoes|0894
2021-05-25|0537|No Longer in Use - Depleted by 2019 Reclass|0537
2021-05-25|1635|Pickleball FW|0021
2021-05-25|0679|Case Sunglasses|0679
2021-05-25|1544|Sandals|0001
2021-05-25|1527|Golf/Tennis Accessories|1059
2021-05-25|1582|Lifestyle FW|0502
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: `\n|` - wouldn't you want `|\n`?

Comment: Great answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the output fairly simply with `awk` using 3-rules. Specifically, you will check that each line begins with a date in your format and ends (e.g. the 4th field `$4`) with 4-digits. If so, just print the line (rule 1). If not, and the line begins with a date in your format, just output without a `'\n'` so you can append the next line to it (rule 2). If you have reach a line that satisfies neither rule 1 or rule 2, it is the end of the previous line, just output with a `'\n'` to complete the previous line (rule 3).

That can be done with:

```
awk -F'|' '
    NF==4 && $4~/^[[:digit:]]{4}$/ { print; next }
    $1~/[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}/ { 
        printf "%s",$0
        next
    }
    { print }
' f.csv
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your input file in `f.csv` you would obtain:

```
$ awk -F'|' '
>     NF==4 && $4~/^[[:digit:]]{4}$/ { print; next }
>     $1~/[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}/ {
>         printf "%s",$0
>         next
>     }
>     { print }
> ' f.csv
DATECODE|SUBCLASSCODE|SUBCLASS_NAME|CLASS
2021-05-25|2202|Bras|1310
2021-05-25|1119|No Longer in Use - Depleted by 2019 Reclass|0805
2021-05-25|0949|No Longer in Use - Depleted by 2021 Reclass|0231
2021-05-25|1928|Fishing Gloves|1155
2021-05-25|1604|Training FW|1080
2021-05-25|0894|Hunting Waders|0894
2021-05-25|1873|Small Game|0326
2021-05-25|9950|EVENTREGISTRATION FEE|9950
2021-05-25|0476|Regular Golf Gloves|0476
2021-05-25|1366|Shorts|0988
2021-05-25|1914|Wade Shoes|0894
2021-05-25|0537|No Longer in Use - Depleted by 2019 Reclass|0537
2021-05-25|1635|Pickleball FW|0021
2021-05-25|0679|Case Sunglasses|0679
2021-05-25|1544|Sandals|0001
2021-05-25|1527|Golf/Tennis Accessories|1059
2021-05-25|1582|Lifestyle FW|0502
```

Which is the output you specified.

You can write it in condensed form with one rule per-line as:

```
awk -F'|' '
    NF==4 && $4~/^[[:digit:]]{4}$/ { print; next }
    $1~/[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}/ { printf "%s",$0; next }
    { print }
' f.csv
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: wow this is perfect! is there a more general way to tackle these kind of situation like if we have more number of columns

Comment: Yes, `awk` is the Swiss-Army Knife of text-processing. It works on records (lines) and fields by applying each rule to the line, in the order you write the rules. You can place a condition before the rules (as we did with rule 1 & rule 2 above) to limit which rule gets applied to which record, etc.. The actual rule writing is largely like C (with almost as much capability) [The GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) is a great place to start. (and `awk` is blisteringly fast, so files with 10,000,000 records are no problem)

Comment: The fields in `awk` are `$1` (first field), `$2` (second field), etc.. The `FS` variable controls the field-separator. When given on the command like, the option is `-F` so `-F '|'` tells awk to use the pipe character as the field-separator. This lets you not only operate on each record, but on each field in each record. And awk understand REGEX -- which greatly increases its matching capabilities.

Comment: @Amin please if this great reply of David is ok for you, choose it as the right one

Answer (score 0):

You have also very simple solution

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ /g;s/2021-/\n2021-/g;s/\| */|/g' input.txt
```

gives you

```
+------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+--------+
| DATECODE   | SUBCLASSCODE | SUBCLASS_NAME                               | CLASS  |
+------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+--------+
| 2021-05-25 | 2202         | Bras                                        | 1310   |
| 2021-05-25 | 1119         | No Longer in Use - Depleted by 2019 Reclass | 0805   |
| 2021-05-25 | 0949         | No Longer in Use - Depleted by 2021 Reclass | 0231   |
| 2021-05-25 | 1928         | Fishing Gloves                              | 1155   |
| 2021-05-25 | 1604         | Training FW                                 | 1080   |
| 2021-05-25 | 0894         | Hunting Waders                              | 0894   |
| 2021-05-25 | 1873         | Small Game                                  | 0326   |
| 2021-05-25 | 9950         | EVENT REGISTRATION FEE                      | 9950   |
| 2021-05-25 | 0476         | Regular Golf Gloves                         | 0476   |
| 2021-05-25 | 1366         | Shorts                                      | 0988   |
| 2021-05-25 | 1914         | Wade Shoes                                  | 0894   |
| 2021-05-25 | 0537         | No Longer in Use - Depleted by 2019 Reclass | 0537   |
| 2021-05-25 | 1635         | Pickleball FW                               | 0021   |
| 2021-05-25 | 0679         | Case Sunglasses                             | 0679   |
| 2021-05-25 | 1544         | Sandals                                     | 0001   |
| 2021-05-25 | 1527         | Golf/Tennis Accessories                     | 1059   |
| 2021-05-25 | 1582         | Lifestyle FW                                | 0502   |
+------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+--------+
```